# Login problems in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.3

Usually we implement the login system in the `UsersController` and we use `User` model(`users` db table). But, I want to implement this login system in different `Controllers`, with different `Models(db tables)`.

So, I have a controller `Admins`, and I have a login function here. This is as usual as I use in `UsersController`. Here, `loginredirect` is a page in the `AdminsController`. But. its not working, it says "Invalid Username or Password, please try again", as I set for the `flash` message. But the same thing works when I change `Admins` controller to `Users` controller, and other related settings.

Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Ooops, sorry, just forgot. Its cakephp-2.3.6 @nedstark

Comment: How did you enter user into db? Did you hash password?

Comment: Yes, users' passwords are encripted while registering. @skywalker

Comment: NOTE: If you want to use different Tables for different roles (e.g. users, admins, customers, etc..) you can summarize your tables to only one instead, using CakePHP´s authorization: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: Without any code it's only possible to guess what you're doing and/or what's happening. Having multiple user models isn't particularly common, and it sounds quite likely that you've setup auth such that it writes to the session in one place in one controller - and it's reading from a different place in another.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I didn't think of that. So, what's your suggession ? @AD7six

Comment: I suggest you add some code to the question :P.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Auth that which model will be used

```
$this->Auth->userModel = 'Admin';
```

Check here in the documentation

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html